# How to transform table with JSON documents columns to several panda data frames

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe in Python pandas with rows of NoSQL documents and json strings column and I want to transform it into flat table with specific keys as column name and values as data in rows. Following is the example table I begin with:

|  | diagnoses |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |

Where 'a' & 'b' looks something like:

```
[{"icd10":"I611","icd10Name":"Intracerebral haemorrhage in hemisphere, cortical","diagType":"1","diagTypeName":"Principal Diagnosis"},{"icd10":"I10","icd10Name":"Essential (primary) hypertension","diagType":"2","diagTypeName":"Comorbidity (โรคอื่นที่เป็นร่วมด้วย)"},{"icd10":"E789","icd10Name":"Disorder of lipoprotein metabolism,unspecified","diagType":"2","diagTypeName":"Comorbidity (โรคอื่นที่เป็นร่วมด้วย)"}]
```

I want to extract this table to another table like:

|  | diagnoses | Principal Diagnoses | Comorbidity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | I611 | I10, E789 |
| 2 | b | ... | ... |

Please feel free to refer to the image here:

[image: img]

Thank you so much in advance. Also, please note that "Principal Diagnoses" doesn't always come first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try working this into a lambda function. loop through dictionaries to separate your values. Assumes principal diagnosis is always single value, but can have 1 or more secondary.

```
data_dict = [{"icd10":"I611","icd10Name":"Intracerebral haemorrhage in hemisphere, cortical","diagType":"1","diagTypeName":"Principal Diagnosis"},{"icd10":"I10","icd10Name":"Essential (primary) hypertension","diagType":"2","diagTypeName":"Comorbidity (โรคอื่นที่เป็นร่วมด้วย)"},{"icd10":"E789","icd10Name":"Disorder of lipoprotein metabolism,unspecified","diagType":"2","diagTypeName":"Comorbidity (โรคอื่นที่เป็นร่วมด้วย)"}]


co_diag = []
for d in data_dict:
    if 'Principal Diagnosis' in d.values():
        pd = d['icd10']
    else:
        co_diag.append(d['icd10'])
        co_diag_str = ', '.join(co_diag)
```

within the steps you should be able to write columns you need.

Output if the loop:

```
In [19]: co_diag_str
Out[19]: 'I10, E789'

In [20]: pd
Out[20]: 'I611'
```

Comment: Thank you, I had to modify it slightly to my function and use ".apply(extract_col) to get the data but it worked. Many thanks:

def extract_col2(list_of_dict, col='icd10'):
    if len(list_of_dict) == 0:
        return []
    
    result = []
    for d in list_of_dict:
        if 'Comorbidity (โรคอื่นที่เป็นร่วมด้วย)' in d.values():
            result.append(d[col])
    return result

Comment: glad you were able to get it to work

Comment: Appreciate that but won't be able to tutor. Maybe someone else will read this and offer or head over to reddit subreddit called pythontips. Great resources there.

Comment: Absolutely thank you Jonathan! :)